# Make a form_for block do nothing in Rails 4.0.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a chat application,and I would like to use HTML5 validation on the text box where the user inputs their message, so that the submit button is disabled until the message is valid.

To do that, I would need a `form_for` block, and I was wondering if you could stop the form from submitting itself like it usually does? I wan't to handle the message sending through JavaScript, jQuery and WebSockets, not through how Rails normally does things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
form_form @resource, html: {class: 'someIdentifier'}
```

Then via jQuery

```
$(function(){
  $('.someIdentifier').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  })
})
```

Hope this help.